# Thumbnails asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, image

I am trying to write an application that **allows a user to click a button to see images as thumbnails** from a folder in a modal popup. Inside of my modal popup I have a datalist. But from there I don't know where to go. I've already tried the 4guysfromrolla solution but it wasn't what I was looking for. How can I set up images as thumbnails? I already have the following....

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Folder1/Folder2/"), "*.jpg")

    For Each File As String In files
        File = File.Substring(File.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, File.Length)
        'Response.Write(File & "<br>")

        File = File & "~/Folder1/Folder2/"

        Dim image As Image = New Image()
        image.ImageUrl = File
        image.Height = 50
        image.Width = 50
        Me.Controls.Add(image)

    Next
```

**Edited:New Question**

I want to change the size of the images in javascript onmouseover.

```
image.Attributes.add("onmouseover","change size here")

Panel2.controls.add(image)
```

Is it possible to do this here?

Comment: Ok, then it looks like you've done the thumbnail modal window. What is the thing you want to ask ??

Comment: Sorry, I made it a little more clear.

Comment: Is there any reason why your question is tagged C# while your code snippet is in VB.NET?

Comment: I can read and write in both. I think most write in C# and are more prone to view the question.

Comment: Pull up FireBug and see if you are getting 404 for ur images... your ImageUrl generation looks wrong?

Comment: that Edit should be a different question on stackoverflow, and its easy. look into jQuery , or YUI, Event listeners and adding and removing css classes

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl_thumbs" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <img src="<%# Eval("imageUrl") %>" height="50" width="50" title="<%# Eval("imageTitle") %>" alt="<%# Eval("imageAlt") %>"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>



private void InitData(string folder)
{

    var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(folder));



    var images = files.Select(i =>
                        new
                        {
                            imageUrl = folder + Path.GetFileName(i),
                            imageTitle = Path.GetFileName(i),
                            imageAlt = Path.GetFileName(i)
                        });

    dl_thumbs.DataSource = images;
    dl_thumbs.DataBind();
}
```

How are the image files save in you folder structure?

Thumbnails are usually processed and optimized versions of an original file.

Original file 500x500, then thumbs would be processed down to 50x50.

You should have 2 ( or more versions of you images.. )

> myfavImageName.jpg
>
> myfavImageName.thumb.jpg

or even add another folder [ Thumbs ]

> /Folder1/Folder2/myfavImageName.jpg
>
> /Folder1/Folder2/thumbs/myfavImageName.jpg

You can also use Path to get file name. its less error prone:

```
filename =  Path.GetFileName(File);
```

Comment: Hey, check out my question under edited. Have you any experience with that?

Comment: that should be a different question on stackoverflow

Comment: check it out....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178397/change-size-of-image-control-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/folder1/folder2/"), "*.jpg")
    For Each File As String In files
        Dim substr As String = File.Substring(0, File.LastIndexOf("\"))

        File = File.Replace(substr, "")

        File = "~/Folder1/Folder2" & File
        Dim image As Image = New Image()
        image.ImageUrl = File
        image.Height = 50
        image.Width = 50
        Panel1.Controls.Add(image)
        'Panel1.FindControl("dlpictures").Controls.Add(image)
    Next
```