# Change size of image control in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, vb.net, image

I want to change the size of the images in javascript onmouseover.

Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Folder1/Folder2/"), "*.jpg")

```
For Each File As String In files
    File = File.Substring(File.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, File.Length)
    'Response.Write(File & "<br>")

    File = File & "~/Folder1/Folder2/"

    Dim image As Image = New Image()
    image.ImageUrl = File
    image.Height = 50
    image.Width = 50
    Me.Controls.Add(image)
    image.Attributes.add("onmouseover","change size here")

    Panel2.controls.add(image)
Next
```

Is it possible to do this here?

**Here is some HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup = "none"/>
                            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" 
                                style="display:none; background-color:Transparent; padding:1em 6px;" BackColor="White">
                                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" style="background-color:Black;" Width="265px">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" CssClass="bttnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"
                                                ImageUrl="~/images/bttnCancel.gif" ValidationGroup = "none" />                                       
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Add some of what the HTML looks like when its sent to the client.

Comment: is the added html sufficient?

Comment: I might suggest taking a look at http://imageresizing.net, as that will allow you to perform *true* image resizing, rather than javascript faking. To use the library, just add "?width=100" to the image URL from your javascript snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend setting this JS functionality cleint side:

Depending on how your images are added to the html doc. you can use jQuery to listen to the events and alter the size of ur images...

look into jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("img.thumbImg").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr("height", "100").attr("width", "100");
    }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("height", "50").attr("width", "50");
    })

});
```

add to code behind

```
image.CssClass = "thumbImg";
```

Add the css class to Panel2

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server"  CssClass="thumbs"  style="background-color:Black;" Width="265px">
```

You could also just add / remove CssClasses, 
you might need to fine tune the js to match ur html, use the the online documentation to help you, but this is the answer

Comment: i am getting an object expected error for the script you recommended above. Do I have this set up correctly? Does Jquery know to use the correct img tag?